# Encountering undefined behavior on a function to add up numbers below 10

Tags: c, scanf, undefined-behavior

I am encountering UB in the terminal with my current code when the input contains comma, dot or non-only-numeric character. I am confused why that is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

float tizAlatti(int inputCount);

int main(){
    int inputNumber;
    printf("Number of input elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &inputNumber);
    if(inputNumber % 1 != 0 && (isdigit(inputNumber) == 0)){
    printf("Error encountered.");
    exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n%.2f", tizAlatti(inputNumber));
}
float tizAlatti(int inputCount){
    float arr[inputCount], input = 0;
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<inputCount; i++){
        printf("Element %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
        if(arr[i] < 10){
            input+= arr[i];
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Here I got this output for *"h"* input. It's not its ASCII code value, which was a false assumption by me.
[image: "h" input]

I also got this output for *"5.6"* input.
[image: "5.6" input]

I worked out that the issue lays somewhere in the `if()` part in the `main()` function, as the tizAlatti function gets invoked in the main for an input, but I don't know what this problem exactly is. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You should check that scanf worked by looking at it's return value

Comment: what's your goal with inputNumber % 1 != 0?

Comment: It does when I provide an input that has only numbers in it, and nothing else

Comment: To check if an integer was given by the user, so the remainder should be zero @johnelemans

Comment: *"To check if an integer was given by the user"* - you should check the return value of `scanf` to confirm whether an integer was correctly provided. If one wasn't, `inputNumber` will contain an *indeterminate* value. Reading this value will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) - and no amount of modulus is going to help.

Comment: Note: [`isdigit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isdigit.3p.html) is for testing if a single *character* (`'A'`, `'$'`, etc.), represented as an `unsigned char`, is in the digit character class of the current locale. Its argument is of type `int` to cover the range of `unsigned char`, as well as `EOF`, a negative value. Testing a random integer value makes little sense.

Comment: István Csige, what text or who suggested `inputNumber % 1 != 0`?

Comment: It was just my thought that an integer gives zero remainder when divided by one, turns out it's not that simple to verify the cases @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Since you will read integers and floats over and over again in your code, it makes sense to write a function to handle those tasks that you can simply include in any code you write going forward rather than reinventing the wheel each time. Having the function take an optional prompt to display is convenient as well. Reading `arr[]` with `for(int i = 0; i<inputCount; i++)` makes it impossible to handle bad input without also incrementing `i`. Only increment `i` after a *successful* read.

Answer (score 1):

> I am encountering UB in the terminal with my current code when the input contains comma, dot or non-only-numeric character.

Neither `scanf("%d", &inputNumber)` nor `scanf("%f", &arr[i]);` ever read these characters<sup>*1</sup>, so they remain in `stdin` until something does read them.  This also blocks following input.

As `scanf("%d", &inputNumber)` and `scanf("%f", &arr[i])` then do not assign `inputNumber` or `arr[i]`, that value is indeterminant leading to subsequent trouble.

Check the return value of `scanf()` and if not 1, exit or use other code to read/consume the non-numeric input and try again.

Even better, use `fgets()` to read a line of user input and stop using `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.

---

<sup>*1</sup> `'.'` as a decimal point is read by `scanf("%f", &arr[i])`.